# VS Code: Can't call function in editor altough it works in Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm trying to call a function in the vs Code editor:

```
def function(nr):
    newnr = nr*2
    return newnr

function(3)
```

but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

The strange thing is when I put everything in the Terminal it works:

```
>>> def function(nr):
...     newnr = nr*2
...     return newnr
...
>>> function(6)
12
```

Once the function is defined in Terminal I can call it from the Editor.

So I deleted the Terminal and ran the progam without the function call--> same error code

```
def function(nr):
    newnr = nr*2
    return newnr
```

What am I missing to define a function within the terminal?

Below is a screenshot:

I tried to use Shift+Enter which puts it into the console doesn't work for the whole function though. So i used the green Debug Button upper left corner.

Thanks a lot

[screenshot after running with green debug button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoP5g.png)

[screeenshot of my vs-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgMjU.png)

Comment: How do you launch your script? Works fine in my VS Code

Comment: can you add screenshots of how you are trying to run the code and/or even the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Shift+Enter` executes the current line, not the whole file.

To execute the file, select `Python: Current file` instead of `No Configuration` or create your own launch configuration. Then press F5 to start debugging.

Edit: The screenshot that you added in the question (using the green button) shows that it is properly working. Note that executing a command in the terminal will print the output automatically, whereas executing a file does not. Thus, you have to add `print(function(3))` if you want to print the result.